# Расчет высоты label

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Имеется цикл при котором создается определенное количество UILabel, каждый UILabel может иметь от одной до трех строк, нужно как то задать им, высоты таким образом, что бы никто из них не наезжал друг на друга и находили один под другим.

Пример кода

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
UILabel* labelNameItems;

labelNameItems = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
CGRectMake(15, 210 + 15 * i , 160, 15)];

Главным вопрос, рассчитать количество строк... что бы правильно рассчитать высоту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `UILabel` есть метод `sizeThatFits`, который возвращает размер, при котором весь текст поместится (с учетом размера шрифта и т.д.)

```
NSString *text = @"lorem ipsum whatever text";
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 0)];
label.text = text;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(100, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectSize = [label sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
CGRect frame = label.frame;
frame.size = expectSize;
label.frame = frame;
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: спасибо вам, завтра потестирую...

Comment: Спасибо помогло.